# android - SharedPreferences - modifying multiple values - order of value change

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I do the following:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getSharedPreferences(context,
                                     Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putBoolean("boolean_1", true).putInt("int_1", 1);
edit.apply();
```

In what order will `onSharedPreferencesChanged(String key, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences)` be called? `(key == "boolean_1")` first, and then `(key == "int_1")`; or is it the other way around? Or is it neither of those scenarios, but rather another type of ordering, perhaps alpha/num sorting of keys, or by type + alpha?

Also, would the following do the exact same thing as the above code?

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getSharedPreferences(context,
                                     Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putBoolean("boolean_1", true)
edit.putInt("int_1", 1);
edit.apply();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see implementation at [android source, line 399](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7f9f99ea11051614a7727dfb9f9578b518e76e3c/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java).

As I see, all changed keys are added into Map, so i can suggest tha it will be in alphabetical order.

Futher, `onSharedPreferenceChanged` will be called from end of Map to begin (line 450).
So, in your example first will be called with `(key == "int_1")` and second `(key == "boolean_1")`.

Also, there is no matter how you put changes - as in first or in the second code, all listeners will be notified after calling `apply()`.

Comment: So from what I understand, in the my example, when the onSharedPreferencesChangedListener is triggered, both keys will already have been modified?